# Replace IN with EXISTS or COUNT. How to do it. What is missing here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using IN keyword in the query in the middle of a section. Since I am using nested query and want to replace `In` with `Exists` due to performance issues that my seniors have told me might arise.

**Am I missing some column, what you are looking for in this query. This query contain some aliases  for readibility.**

How can I  remove it.

```
SELECT  TX.PK_MAP_ID AS MAP_ID 
        , MG.PK_GUEST_ID AS Guest_Id 
        , MG.FIRST_NAME 
        , H.PK_CATEGORY_ID AS Preference_Id 
        , H.DESCRIPTION AS Preference_Name 
        , H.FK_CATEGORY_ID AS Parent_Id 
        , H.IMMEDIATE_PARENT AS Parent_Name 
        , H.Department_ID 
        , H.Department_Name 
        , H.ID_PATH, H.DESC_PATH 
FROM          
    dbo.M_GUEST AS MG  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.TX_MAP_GUEST_PREFERENCE AS TX  
            ON  
                (MG.PK_GUEST_ID = TX.FK_GUEST_ID) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.GetHierarchy_Table AS H  
            ON  
                (TX.FK_CATEGORY_ID = H.PK_CATEGORY_ID) 
WHERE      
    (MG.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
        AND  
    (TX.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
        AND  
    (H.Department_ID IN -----How to remove this IN operator with EXISTS or Count() 
              ( 
                SELECT C.PK_CATEGORY_ID AS DepartmentId 
                FROM  
                    dbo.TX_MAP_DEPARTMENT_OPERATOR AS D  
                        INNER JOIN 
                    dbo.M_OPERATOR AS M  
                            ON   
                                (D.FK_OPERATOR_ID = M.PK_OPERATOR_ID) 
                                    AND  
                                (D.IS_ACTIVE = M.IS_ACTIVE) 
                        INNER JOIN 
                    dbo.L_USER_ROLE AS R  
                            ON   
                                (M.FK_ROLE_ID = R.PK_ROLE_ID) 
                                    AND  
                                (M.IS_ACTIVE = R.IS_ACTIVE) 
                        INNER JOIN 
                    dbo.L_CATEGORY_TYPE AS C  
                            ON  
                                (D.FK_DEPARTMENT_ID = C.PK_CATEGORY_ID) 
                                    AND  
                                (D.IS_ACTIVE = C.IS_ACTIVE) 
                WHERE       
                    (D.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
                        AND  
                    (M.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
                        AND  
                    (R.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
                        AND  
                    (C.IS_ACTIVE = 1)  
            )--END INNER QUERY 
    )--END Condition
```

What new problems might I get if I replace IN with EXISTS or COUNT ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, as I understand your question, you are asking how can I replace this:

```
where H.department_id in (select departmentid from...)
```

with this:

```
where exists (select...)
```

or this:

```
where (select count(*) from ...) > 1
```

It is fairly straight forward.  One method might be this:

```
WHERE...
  AND EXISTS (select c.pk_category_id 
              from tx_map_department_operator d
                inner join m_operator as m
                  on    d.fk_operator_id = m.pk_operator_id
                inner join l_user_role l
                  on m.fk_role_id = r.pk_role_id
                inner join l_category_type c
                  on d.fk_department_id = c.pk_category_id
               where h.department_id = c.pk_category_id
                 and d.is_active = 1 
                 and m.is_active = 1 
                 and r.is_active = 1 
                 and c.is_active = 1
              )
```

I removed the extra joins on is_active because they were redundant.  You should test how it runs with your indexes, because that might have been faster.  I doubt it though.  But it is worth comparing whether it is faster to add the join clause (`join on ... and x.is_active=y.is_active`) or to check in the where clause (`x.is_active=1 and y.is_active=1 and z.is_active=1...`)

And I'd recommend you just use `exists`, instead of `count(*)`, because I know that exists should stop after finding 1 row, whereas count probably continues to execute until done, and then compares to your reference value (count > 1).

As an aside, that is a strange column naming standard you have.  Do you really have PK prefixes for the primary keys, and FK prefixes for the foreign keys?  I have never seen that.

Comment: Yeah I thought the naming standard is annoying as well. They surely make the queries less readable.

Comment: SIN: I do agree naming convention is bit absurd, but i m not the PM nor TL, just an SE so cant change it and have to follow what has been told to us, sry for that cant help out myself in it. Here my question is what is the affect of removing H.Department. As what i think here is how would it be getting the same result.

Comment: I think it should have joined to the H table.  Changes made above.  But now I am not sure I understand the intent.  Using the H table inside the inner query will likely slow it down dramatically.